# How to resize UIView by dragging from it's edges

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, resize

I'm making a photo based iPhone app. Inside the view that has a custom AVFoundation camera, I create a subview that is used for taking picture only of the area that's inside the subview. Think of it as a view for cropping an image.

The View is being resized by changing the width and height constant (I would like to preserve the size of the other subviews inside the crop view). Everything works perfectly when I drag from the bottom left corner, however when I start dragging from other corners I get inverse behaviour (I drag outside, the view shrinks and vice versa) - I figured out that this is due to the fact that I get the negative values as I calculate the change from the center of crop view. Could you please help me with finding the right algorithm that would prevent this behaviour?

Thank you so much! :]

**Here is the custom class for the CropView**

> The CROP_OPTIONS is used for cropping the images

```
import UIKit

//CROP OPTIONS
struct CROP_OPTIONS {
    var Height: CGFloat!
    var Width: CGFloat!
    var Center: CGPoint!
}

var  _cropoptions: CROP_OPTIONS!

class CropView: UIView {

    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 1.5
    let strokeColor = giveColor(color: .mainBlue)

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        self.layer.borderColor = strokeColor.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = lineWidth
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        _cropoptions = CROP_OPTIONS()
        _cropoptions.Center = self.center
        _cropoptions.Width = self.bounds.width
        _cropoptions.Height = self.bounds.height

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    var startPosition: CGPoint?
    var originalHeight: CGFloat = 0
    var originalWidth: CGFloat = 0

    var customViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var customViewWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        startPosition = touch?.location(in: self)
        originalHeight = customViewHeight.constant //self.frame.height
        originalWidth = customViewWidth.constant //self.frame.width
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let endPosition = touch?.location(in: self)

        let differenceY = endPosition!.y - startPosition!.y
        var newHeight: CGFloat = originalHeight + differenceY

        newHeight = (newHeight < 75) ? 75.0 : newHeight
        newHeight = (newHeight > 225) ? 225 : newHeight
        customViewHeight.constant = newHeight

        let differenceX = endPosition!.x - startPosition!.x
        var newWidth: CGFloat = originalWidth + differenceX

        newWidth = (newWidth < 75.0) ? 75.0 : newWidth
        newWidth = (newWidth > 350) ? 350.0 : newWidth
        customViewWidth.constant = newWidth

        _cropoptions.Center = self.center
        _cropoptions.Height = self.frame.height
        _cropoptions.Width = self.frame.width
    }
}
```

Comment: Utilise print() to print values to the console and view them change as you drag around. Your problem will likely be an inverse number or something that would be easy to pick up with a few print statements

Comment: @MichaelHudsonhey Hi Michael, yeah I've gotten the values - they are being inverse, but the reason why I posted this question is because I can't figure out the algorithm that I need to use. Or to be honest, how to understand in which section of the UIView is the touch -> top left x top right x bottom left x bottom right. Do you know how to do this?